# Trouble with 'where' on nested fields in graphql

Tags: strapi

I'm pretty new to Strapi,React and Graphql; so still learning...

I've got the following GraphQL query:

```
query {
  specification(id: "5eb170c556d84a7b6e8e6456") {
    id
    Collaborators{
      id
      Acronym
        collaboratorType
      collaboratorName
      ProfessionalRecognition
    }
  }
}
```

This is working, but I'd like to be able to filter the results of Collaborators based on the value of ProfessionalRecognition (which is a boolean). However, no matter how I try to construct a `where` statement, it simply returns errors.

Can someone give me some assistance in defining the query that return only those Collaborators `where ProfessionalRecognition is 'true'`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try  below graphql query

```
query {
  specifications(where:{
  id:"5eb170c556d84a7b6e8e6456",
  Collaborators:{
    ProfessionalRecognition:true
  }
  }) {
    id
    Collaborators{
      id
      Acronym
        collaboratorType
      collaboratorName
      ProfessionalRecognition
    }
  }
}
```

For more information on nested filtering , Please refer to the blog article
[Perform nested filtering with graphql queries in strapi](https://ns23.dev/blog/strapi-deep-filtering-with-graphql/)

Comment: This results in: ```Your filters contain a field 'Collaborators.ProfessionalRecognition' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations```

However, the field `ProfessionalRecognition` does exist, because I can return values without the filters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `ProfessionalRecognition` is defined. I'd need to see the type definition.

Try something like this:

```
query {
  specification(id: "5eb170c556d84a7b6e8e6456") {
    id
    Collaborators(where: {ProfessionalRecognition: true}){
      id
      Acronym
        collaboratorType
      collaboratorName
      ProfessionalRecognition
    }
  }
}
```

But if it's nested, it could be something like this:

```
query {
  specification(id: "5eb170c556d84a7b6e8e6456") {
    id
    Collaborators(where: {ProfessionalRecognition: {someField: true} }){
      id
      Acronym
        collaboratorType
      collaboratorName
      ProfessionalRecognition
    }
  }
}
```